# Laplace of $e^{-s+3}$?

Tags: laplace-transform

I understand that the $e^{-ks}$ will time shift the function in the time domain by $k$ and will result in a time function of $u(t-3)$, but what does it mean when you have $e^{-s-k}$? How will that affect the function?

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathcal{L}\left(e^{ax+k}\right)=e^k\mathcal{L}\left(e^{ax}\right)=e^k\frac{1}{s-a}$$ because the constant $e^k$ factors out by linearity of the transform.

Comment: So it just acts as a constant?

Comment: Well it *is* a constant, unless $k$ is a function of something...

Comment: right, I mean whereas in the first example it's a time shift, in the second example, it acts to make the function larger or smaller, by a factor of e^-k

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @JFA Any chance you mean "find the Laplace transform of $e^{-t+3}$"? If we have the variable $s$ such as in your title (find $e^{-s+3}$), then we can only take the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: @glacier Hopefully that's what they mean, because that's what I did!

Comment: @glacier That's not what I meant at all. I meant what I wrote

Comment: @JFA Well I'm not sure what you wrote makes much sense; maybe you could try re-wording the questions?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: @JFA Not really, sorry :) Um, does what I wrote make sense though? Did I answer your question? I'm not really sure if I nailed it or completely misinterpreted what you are asking...

Comment: I guess my question is,other than growing or shrinking the function by a factor of a power of e, does it have any affect on the function. I'm confused as to why these problems all suddenly say e^(s-k) and I'm wondering if I should be treating it differently or simply pulling it out to the front like a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant find the Laplace of $e^{-t+3}$, instead of $e^{-s+3}$, then hope this helps.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{e^{-t+3}\}&=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}(e^{-t+3}) \, dt  \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t(s+1)}e^3 \, dt \\ 
&=e^3 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t(s+1)} \cdot (1) \, dt & e^3 \text{ is a constant value; move it outside the integral} \\ 
&=e^3 \mathcal{L}\{1\}_{s \rightarrow s+1} \\
&=e^3 \frac{1}{s+1}
\end{align}
Normally, $\mathcal{L}\{1\}=\frac{1}{s}$, but note the fact that we are replacing the variable $s$ with $s+1$. Hence, $\mathcal{L}\{1\}_{s \rightarrow s+1}=\frac{1}{s+1}$.

Comment: No, there was not a transcription error in what I wrote. I meant `e^(-s+3)`